# Why does my C++ code for a horizontal bar graph not allow user input?

Tags: c++

Here is my code. This is done in c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int input [1];
    int n = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        cout << "usage: bargraph integer-list \n"; /*This is the only thing showing up in my terminal*/
        cin >> n;
    }
    for (int b=0; b < 1; b++)
    {
        cout << b;
        for (int j=0; j<input[j]; j++)
        {
            cout << "#";
        }
        cout << "/n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like this to be able to enter in as many user inputs as the user wants.

Comment: When you reach the condition `j < input[j]`, what is the value of `input[j]`, and how many elements does `input` have?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Also there are a lot of wrong things in the code. If I were you, I would write it from scratch again

Comment: The input could be whatever. There is no restrictions on input

Comment: Your input loop will set `n` to the last input value; thus I recommend replacing the loop with a simple `std::cin >> n;`.

Comment: Why do you have a `for` loop for inputting one value?

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
    int input [1];
```

Here you apparently want to allow more than 1 item to be entered, but your `input` array can only hold one value. One way to support an arbitrary number of values would be to use an `std::vector<int>` instead of an array of int. You can use `push_back` to add items to the vector.

```cpp
    cout << "usage: bargraph integer-list \n";
```

This has a fundamental problem: if you enter the integers on the command line, your program will see them as elements of `argv`, which is passed as a parameter to `main`. Data you read from standard input has to be entered separately (or the user can use command-line redirection to read standard input from a file of their choice). Either one can/will work fine, but you need to write the code to support the one you choose, and the user is almost certain to get confused if you tell them to do one, but actually support the other.

```cpp
    for (int b=0; b < 1; b++)
    {
        cout << b;
        for (int j=0; j<input[j]; j++)
```

I'd guess you intended:

```
int  j=0; j<input[b]; j++)
// ---------------^
```

You used `j` where you almost certainly intended to use `b`.

One way to prevent problems like that is to use more meaningful variable names. If you used something like `current_line` and `line_length` instead of `b` and `j`:

```cpp
for (int current_line = 0; current_line < count; current_line++)
    for (int line_length = 0; line_length < input[line_length]; line_length++)
```

...the problem would probably be at least somewhat more apparent.